# D3 v4 normal bar chart to stacked using json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, django-rest-framework

I have a bar chart that is working and showing correct data. 
I am now trying to convert it into a stacked bar chart, that shows separate color for different categories. 
I have tried using examples from online and spent pretty long time googling, but I always end up with errors that I don't seem to be able to get rid of.

The biggest issue I seem to face is in `d3.json(urljson,...)`. It seems that I'm overseeing some trick to get it to read the data. 
Usually get the error `cannot read property *something* of undefined`. I really only need help with getting it to stack, then I can figure the rest out (getting it in correct colors and all that).

If you have any tips on where to start with the converting, since I've tried and started over 6 times, that would also be really helpful.

I do realize that there are a few changes that need to be made in order to go from a regular bar chart to a stacked one.

I looked at other examples here on Stack too, but none of those approaches worked for me.

The code I'm working with looks like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left:40},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json(urljson, function(error, data) {
    data = data.results;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.sum_value = +d.sum_value ;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.date}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.sum_value })]);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Values");

    g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.date); })
            .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.sum_value ); })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) {return height - y(d.sum_value );})
            .text(function(d) {return y(d.sum_value ); })
});
```

The JSON is provided through Django-rest-framework from Oracle DB, and it looks like this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 32,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "date": "2017-09-22",
            "type": "A",
            "sum_value": 102
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-09-22",
            "type": "Random",
            "sum_value": 32
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-09-22",
            "type": "B",
            "sum_value": 1
        },
        {
            "wo_dt": "2017-09-22",
            "work_type": "A",
            "sum_mh": 85
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-09-25",
            "type": "C",
            "sum_value": 2
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-09-26",
            "type": "B",
            "sum_value": 487
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-09-26",
            "type": "Random",
            "sum_value": 87
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-09-26",
            "type": "A",
            "sum_value": 110
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `date` is the field that I'm grouping together, `sum_value` is the height of each color and `type` is the part that separates the colors.
Where it says Random it's supposed to show different colors than A, B and C and show a different color for each random.

Comment: urljson is not defined, urljson="data.json" ?

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi urljson is taken from a server, but the server is only inhouse, so it's not accessible. 
I have it working for a normal bar chart though, so that's not the problem.